# How to clear a jquery droppable element using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little problem in that I am trying to erase the content appended into my droppable div by using a button.

```
$(":button").click(function(){
        $(ui.draggable).remove.fadeOut(20000);        
    });
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to target the elements that are being dropped as seen [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/124/). I want the appended elements removed and I want the button that was being used to fade away. I would be grateful for any tips helping me with this and any tips moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the click event to delegate to future events, have a look at using jquery .on(). Also, when you call .remove, the element will be removed and you will never see the fade out effect. Have a look at using something along the lines of:

```
$(":button").on("click", function() {
    $(ui.draggable).fadeOut(20000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation, but this did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

At first you must specify an var to use for append buton: `var hui = $("<input type='button' name='Sub' value='clear'/>");`

then you can trigger the click

```
$(hui).click(function(){
    alert(hui.length) ;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/128/

after this you must specify one more var to get ui.draggable

see working variant: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/130/

excuse my self for my english...